# How to identify just one lowest number under same category

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a table, e.g.

```
- Category / Price
- A / 500
- A / 200
- A / 200
- B / 1000
- B / 2000
- B / 1000
```

How to find just ONE lowest number under each category by excel formulas, or VBA (even there are 2 lowest value under same category)?

My expected outcome will be:

```
- Category / Price / CheckLowest
- A / 500 / 
- A / 200 / TRUE
- A / 200 / 
- B / 1000 / TRUE
- B / 2000 / 
- B / 1000 /
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it using an **Array Formula** as in Column **C**. You need to press `Ctrl+Shft+Enter` in order to run this formula correctly. However, you may drag the formula once entered in first cell (Cell **C2** in this case).

```
=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,$B$2:$B$7,""))
```

Column **D** has normal formula, just press enter as usual.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2,$B$1:B2,C2)=1
```

Following is the screenshot with formulas:

[image: Formulas:]

And following is the output:

[image: Output]

You may also solve it using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a UDF in VBA which should solve your problems. Assuming you are familiar with VBA, the code is as follows:

```
Function Price_Checker(Target As String, Rg As Range) As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim arr As Variant
Dim Price As Double
Dim Low_Price As Double

Low_Price = 1E+99
arr = Rg

For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    If arr(i, 1) = Target Then
        Price = arr(i, 2)
        If Price < Low_Price Then
            Low_Price = Price
        End If
    End If
Next i

Price_Checker = Low_Price

End Function
```

Equally, the MINIFS function seems to work just as effectively.

> =MINIFS(Price Range, Product Range, Target Product)

Just replace the above with the actual cells/ranges

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula to `C2` cell then drag down and right as needed.

```
=IF(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,$B$2:$B$7,""),1)=B2,TRUE,"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]